# JavaFX 8: Putting a default "x" mark via css if the checkbox is deselected

Tags: java, css, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I want to be able to control my JavaFX checkbox mark shape on states selected and deselected via css.

I can control the mark properties in selected state using this:

```
.check-box:selected .mark {
    -fx-background-color: gb-control-btn-color;
}
```

How do I do it if it's unselected? Bottomline, I just want X if it's deselected and check (default) if it's selected.

I already tried doing this to no avail:

```
.check-box:normal .mark {
    -fx-shape: "M2,0L5,4L8,0L10,0L10,2L6,5L10,8L10,10L8,10L5,6L2,10L0,10L0,8L4,5L0,2L0,0Z";
    -fx-background-color: gb-control-btn-color;
}
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: There is no `:normal` pseudoclass unless you add it yourself (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#checkbox). However you can overwrite values in the `.check-box:selected .mark` rule since it's more concrete than `.check-box .mark`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no pseudo class **:normal**. Simply leave it off, to style the unselected Checkbox.

```
 .check-box:selected > .box > .mark {
    -fx-shape: "M-0.25,6.083c0.843-0.758,4.583,4.833,5.75,4.833S14.5-1.5,15.917-0.917c1.292,0.532-8.75,17.083-10.5,17.083C3,16.167-1.083,6.833-0.25,6.083z";
 }

 .check-box > .box > .mark {
     -fx-shape: "M2,0L5,4L8,0L10,0L10,2L6,5L10,8L10,10L8,10L5,6L2,10L0,10L0,8L4,5L0,2L0,0Z";
     -fx-background-color: black;
 }
```

There is an invaluable resource when styling JavaFx components at [modena.css](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470), which is a copy of the default JavaFx stylesheet. Search for "checkbox" to see how the default checkbox is styled.